# How to start a Rails 3 app with HAML and SASS as the default templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

the line

```
rails new someapp -m haml
```

doesn't work.  It seems to need a path to some where.

**Update:** `haml-rails` is in fact installed by `gem install haml-rails` but the line above wouldn't work.

Comment: Hey .. What's the deal!?

Answer (score 9):

**The really short version**

Generate a new rails app based on a simple template that sets up Haml out of the box (and some other nice optional features).

```
rails new ProjectName -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/master/rails3-haml-html5-template.rb
```

http://decielo.com/articles/377/haml-by-default-in-a-new-rails-3-2-app

Also check this out:

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer

EDIT:

If you want to do this through the "gem" you simply need to run the default command

`rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb`

This is a safe command as it points to the master branch of the gem and will be a stable URL. Once you have run this command you will be prompted with options. Simply select HAML and SASS when asked by the wizard.

Comment: can it be a gem instead?  because doing something based on a URL path feels a bit unstable -- what if the path points to somewhere that has something that keep changing?

Answer (score 5):

Gem `haml-rails` allows to generate **views** in Haml, but not the initial layout.

After running `rails new someapp` (note: w/o `-m haml`) and adding line `gem "haml-rails"` to your `Gemfile`, you just need to rename `application.html.erb` to `application.html.haml` and manually convert its content from ERB to Haml.

After that, all generated views will be in Haml.

Answer (score 5):

app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title "HAML'd"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
```

Comment: For purists, the content can be generated by `html2haml application.html.erb application.html.haml`

Comment: In Rails 7 (and I think 5+) you can just run `rails haml:erb2haml` which is provided by the `haml-rails` gem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the `haml-rails` gem installed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add `gem 'haml-rails'` to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial, but make sure you restart your rails server after adding the haml gems and run `bundle install`. This got me the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

Install the gem html2haml and you can instantly change the html content to haml from within vim. Have a look at this - http://www.economyofeffort.com/2014/07/20/convert-html-to-haml-within-vim-buffer/